# Auto restarting chrome

Tags: google-chrome, flash, restart

I am running a huge flash app on a pc. The pc is always on and after about a week chrome crashes(memory leak - program is too huge to re-code). Is there a way to auto restart it at a specified time everyday?

Regards
Luben

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you're using Windows, you could use the windows task scheduler, and create a daily task. You can specify tasks to either run a program or a batch script.

For more information about that, have a look at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569

Under Linux/Unix you could use a cronjob.

EDIT: If you use a batch script, you can also test, if chrome is already running. Again, this solution is only for windows (Actually i only tested it with Win7). To test if an application (notepad for this example) you can use the following code:

```
tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq notepad.exe" | find /i "notepad.exe" >nul && (
    echo Windows Media Player is running
) || (
    echo Windows Media Player is not running
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved through Javascript.

```
    <script>

    /*
    Uncomment below line to test this.
    alert('We reloaded!');
    */

    /* Configure when to reload. */
    specified_time = [22,30]; /* [hours, minutes] */


    is_time_to_reload = function(){
        var current_time = new Date();

        return (
            (current_time.getHours() >= specified_time[0]) &&
            (current_time.getMinutes() >= specified_time[1])
        );
    }

    /* We might have just reloaded. This will avoid
         reloading again until the time comes tomorrow */
    if(is_time_to_reload()){
        var not_reload_again_today = true;
        var last_day_reloaded = (new Date()).getDay();
    }

    check_refresh = function(){
        var current_time = new Date();

        if (is_time_to_reload()){
            if (not_reload_again_today &&
                    current_time.getDay() == last_day_reloaded){
                return;
            } else {
                window.location.reload();
            }
        }
    }

    /* check once a minute. */
    setInterval(check_refresh, 60 * 1000); 

    </script>
```

It can also be achieved through HTML, but you wouldn't be able to control the reload time.

```
    <head>
        <!-- refresh page every 86400 seconds. -->
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="86400" />
    </head>
```